# MySQL GROUP BY: Only include rows with specific count of column

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create a query that counts the number of rows which contain the same values for A and B, but only when the occurrence of B for any given A is > 10. In other words, If there were 11 rows in my table as follows:

---

```
| id | A | B | ... |

| 1  | a | a | ... |

| 2  | a | a | ... |

| 3  | a | a | ... |

| 4  | a | a | ... |

| 5  | a | a | ... |

| 6  | a | a | ... |

| 7  | a | a | ... |

| 8  | a | a | ... |

| 9  | a | a | ... |

| 10 | a | a | ... |

| 11 | a | b | ... |
```

---

With the following query:

select A, B, count(B) from foos group by A, B having (?) order by count(B) desc;

I would want the following to return:

```
| a | a | 10 |
```

---

UPDATE/EDIT: There's one other condition I need to check for here; For the given query above, I'd only like rows returned where, in the `GROUP_BY A, B` case, A appears in more than 10 returned rows. So for instance:

```
| 1  | a | a |
| 2  | a | b |
| 3  | a | c |
| 4  | a | d |
| 5  | a | e |
| 6  | a | f |
| 7  | a | g |
| 8  | a | h |
| 9  | a | i |
| 10 | a | j |
| 11 | a | k |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the condition in `having` clause.

```
select A, B, count(B)
from foos
group by A, B 
having count(B) > 10
order by count(B) desc;
```

**Explanation:**

This query will fetch A and B along the count of records where both A and B are same. And will show only those results if the count is greater than 10.

The `HAVING` clause was added to SQL because the `WHERE` clause could not be used with aggregate functions.

**EDIT:**

If you want to group by A and B, then it will not work for the updated table data. In such cases you will have to do it like,

```
select A, count(B)
from foos
group by A
having count(B) > 10
order by count(B) desc
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `count(B)` will only return the total number of rows for each distinct combination of `A` and `B` (not counting any other columns). So using `having count(B) > 10` will simply exclude any `group`ed rows whose `count(B)` is 10 or less?

Comment: @Argus9: This query will fetch A and B along the count of records where both A and B are same. And will show only those results if the count is greater than 10.

Comment: Actually, after running the query, I realized I hadn't explained what I'm looking for sufficiently. I actually need the query to only return rows where any given A appears more than 10 times in the returned rows. Please see the updated description above.

Comment: @Argus9: Try using `having count(B) >=10`.

Comment: This is kind of hard to put into words, but what I mean is, I only want to return rows where the value of `A` would appear with more than 10 unique values of `B`. Effectively, if I `order by A asc`, this would cause `A` to show up at least 11 times, along with the value and count of `B`.

Comment: Hmm...so I have to choose between getting the number of rows grouping A and B, or the number of occurrences of B per each A?

Comment: @Argus9: For getting the count of B for each A, you should use the second query with `select a, count(b) ...group by a...`

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. Assuming I want to also get the total number of rows containing the A/B combo, would it be sufficient to add `count(*)` to the `select` statement, or would that just return the same as `count(B)`? I'm running the query now, but the table is pretty large so it may take some time.

Comment: @Argus9: You can use `count(*)` if you want to count the records where both A and B are same.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help, I appreciate it! I've set yours as the accepted answer. Damn cooldowns! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select A, B, count(B) as count
from foos 
group by A, B 
having (Count>10)
order by count(B) desc;
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score -2):

```
select A, B, count(B)
from foos
where count(B) > 10
group by A
order by count(B) desc;
```